# Close all opened form in windows mobile 6.1 standard application

Tags: c#, .net-cf-3.5

I am creating a windows mobile 6.1 standard application I want to know how to close all the forms which is opened with a single click. I use `Application.Run(new frmLogin());` but it shows exception

> *Value does not fall within the expected range*

Does somebody know how to do this in windows mobile 6.1 standard application?

In other words close all the Windows form except the login Form if                 `Application.Exit();` then it close the login application